# How can get this time formate

Tags: flutter, dart, date-formatting

> I want to ask how can I get like this time formate in flutter

```
2021-09-27T12:22:23.1861335+02:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do this, based on https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted + "+02:00");
}
```

output:

> 2023-01-02T23:08:59.7340000+02:00

Comment: can I generate "+02:00" automatic depend to country

Comment: This is a part you have to figure out yourself. Dont be that lazy.

Comment: no but this number depend to the country so I want to generated automatic

Comment: This is a part you have to figure out yourself. Dont be that lazy.

Comment: Use the DateTime.timeZoneOffset to generate +nnnn or -nnnn depending on the value.